# Pulling specific values from nested dictionaries and arrays in JSON in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-2.7, dictionary

This is a more specific follow up to a previous question that I had asked. Basically, I am trying to pull specific data from a block of JSON text that I received back after processing a GET request. After limiting down to just items (by using the dict.items() method), I am left with the following JSON data (there is a ton of it but this is just a sample):

```
[('response',
  {'count': 84,
   'users': [{'location_id': 123456,
                   'acx_audit': None,
                   'flash_backup_url': u'',
                   'flash_backup_url_secure': u'',
                   'flash_click_variable': None,
                   'folder': None,
                   'format': u'url-json',
                   'height': 1,
                   'id': 36619222,
                   'is_prohibited': False,},
             {'location_id': 5556667,
                   'acx_audit': None,
                   'flash_backup_url': u'',
                   'flash_backup_url_secure': u'',
                   'flash_click_variable': None,
                   'folder': None,
                   'format': u'url-json',
                   'height': 1,
                   'id': 4567777,
                   'is_prohibited': False,}
```

The data I am trying pull is the 'id' number (not 'location_id') for each one of these objects and put all of those numbers gathered into an array. I am struggling a bit though since I am not used to working with big JSON data structures like this where there are dictionaries and arrays nested within each other. Will I have to also run a loop to accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as follows (some stringent conditional checking is involved to avoid exceptions being raised)

```
inp=[('response',
  {'count': 84,
   'users': [{'location_id': 123456,
                   'acx_audit': None,
                   'flash_backup_url': u'',
                   'flash_backup_url_secure': u'',
                   'flash_click_variable': None,
                   'folder': None,
                   'format': u'url-json',
                   'height': 1,
                   'id': 36619222,
                   'is_prohibited': False},
             {'location_id': 5556667,
                   'acx_audit': None,
                   'flash_backup_url': u'',
                   'flash_backup_url_secure': u'',
                   'flash_click_variable': None,
                   'folder': None,
                   'format': u'url-json',
                   'height': 1,
                   'id': 4567777,
                   'is_prohibited': False},
                {'location_id': 5556667,
                   'acx_audit': None,
                   'flash_backup_url': u'',
                   'flash_backup_url_secure': u'',
                   'flash_click_variable': None,
                   'folder': None,
                   'format': u'url-json',
                   'height': 1,
                   'id': 4567777,
                   'is_prohibited': False},
            {'location_id': 5556667,
                   'acx_audit': None,
                   'flash_backup_url': u'',
                   'flash_backup_url_secure': u'',
                   'flash_click_variable': None,
                   'folder': None,
                   'format': u'url-json',
                   'height': 1,
                   'id': 4567777,
                   'is_prohibited': False}]})]
output=[]
for tup_el in inp:
    for el in tup_el:
        if type(el) is dict:
            if "users" in el.keys():
                if type(el["users"]) is list:
                    for obj in el["users"]:
                        if "id" in obj.keys():
                            output.append(obj['id'])
print output
```

Comment: Thank you @repzero, this works perfectly. So if I understand this correctly, this code runs through the json and checks to see if it's a list, dict, key and then after finding 'id', it adds each ID to the array (which is output). Do I have that correct?